# asking how to use the correct (latest) c++ code in a particular situation

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

There are various changes to the C++ language that the newer versions bring and actually improves either the developer's life or code quality.

If the questioner wants to know the latest method / form of doing something in C++ 11 or the upcoming 14, they may refer to terms such as "the proper way", "the best way", "the latest way" etc. Surely, this isn't opinion-based when it could bring answers introducing smart pointers etc? So should questions with such terms in c++ be closed because of a slight mis-use of the English language, especially if not asked by a native speaker?

Comment: proper is clearly opinion-based, best nearly as much (what's your metric?). The latest way though... not sure about that.

Comment: see, in my opinion, "proper" is not opinion-based as I would take it to refer to the latest form, and yes, I'm a native speaker!

Comment: In that case, what's the proper coding style? I always wanted a definite answer there.

Comment: Remember that questions have to have age well. What is up-to-date now might not be in a year or two.

Comment: @gunr2171 so reference is made to c++11 / 14 in the answer?

Comment: If you say it's for a particular version of c++ (like 11 or 14), that's fine. If you say "in general", that will invalidate the answers in the future.

Comment: interesting, and if the tag c++11 is used without mentioning it in the question?

Comment: It would to be good to be explicit about the version, as well as using the version tag.

Comment: could such questions be edited to add the relevant tag, or change the phrase to "latest"?

Comment: Recommended reading: [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/102937)

Comment: The tour of stackoverflow suggests that questions about "Coding techniques" are perfectly acceptable.

Comment: You should look through the recent upvoted questions in the c++11 tag. It will help you to write a clear on-topic question if you see the outline and format of other well-written posts.

Answer (score 1):

Of course its opinion based.  For example, my opinion is 90% of the new spec is crap and the authors did the language a huge disservice.  I  also think any use of templates outside of container classes should be punished with the removal of both hands so you can never inflict your code on the world again.  And actually not an insignificant percentage of C++ users agree with me.  Just because something is newer does not mean that it's better.  I find most of the code written with the "new" C++ tools to be completely unmaintainable and would reject them in a code review.  And anyone who uses auto should be shot, we have strong typing for a reason-  it avoids bugs.  I think the 2014 spec should be ignored and we all pretend it never happened-  our code will be better for it-  it has more negatives than positives.  C++ should be considered finished as of the 2000 era spec and no new features added.  If you want new features make a new language, C++ has too many already.

So asking for the "proper" or the "best" way to do something is off topic.  It's an opinion.  Obviously there are ways to ask for these kinds of questions, but avoid using those terms-  they're inflamatory, cause people to go off topic, and really don't have an answer-  the right answer is whatever has the fewest bugs and is easiest to maintain, which is a very personalized result based on how your developers think about code.  Hence they're closed.

Now if you asked "How do I do X using technique Y?" then you're ok-  if its a totally inappropriate technique I might come in and give an alternative, but I'll probably just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You will certainly find mixed opinions on this, but I'll argue that such questions can be acceptable if they are asked well. I believe that many (or even most) questions have some opinion based component. The close reason in question is named "**primarily** opinion-based". Not "slightly opinion-based". So just because an answer cannot be evaluated 100% objectively, that's not a reason why the question cannot be asked.

To give merit to these kinds of questions, they need to be specific. Say for example you want to learn more about the use of lambda functions. I think "How should I use lambda functions?" (which could be considered "too broad" as well as "primarily opinion-based") would be a bad question. Instead, ask about a specific example, and show how you implemented it without using new features. Then ask if and how lambda functions can be applied to improve your code. Or even better, try to apply them yourself, and ask for feedback/suggestions on how to use them better, or for help if you get stuck.

It really comes down to asking questions that can be answered on a technical level. Even if potential answers can be somewhat subjective, it should be possible to evaluate them with primarily technical criteria. If you're reasonably familiar with a domain, you probably have a very good instinct of what questions can spark interesting technical answers, and which will result in a flame war. As long as you critically read your questions before you hit "Post", and make sure that they fall in the first category, and avoid the second, I think you'll be fine.