# how to ask "is this good practice?" or "is there a better solution than...?"

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have seen (and asked) questions on stack overflow that ask if a solution to a problem is good practice or if there is a better way (perhaps quicker or more efficient) to solve the same problem. As far as I have seen, many people don't like these questions and will downvote them. Are they off topic? Is there a better way to ask them?

Also, in some other questions, the accepted answer is not the best answer because there is a better practice or more efficient solution than that answer. Often the best answer is further down the page even though it has far more upvotes than the accepted answer. Usually because the accepted answer was easier to implement or got there first and just about did the trick. Is the site supposed to cope with this? or should I just read on in such cases to find a better answer than the accepted answer?

Comment: What is "best" is often controversial, thus opinion based.

Comment: Some questions of this type might be on-topic on [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). But please make sure to check with that site's About (and/or  Meta) as well.

Comment: @Angew Aha, right. I didn't know of the code review stack exchange site. Sounds like the right place.

Comment: similar: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266590/asking-how-to-use-the-correct-latest-c-code-in-a-particular-situation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're asking to have a code review.  There's an <s>app</s> [site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) for that.

Of course they have their own set of guidelines for what types of code reviews are and are not acceptable, so be sure to look through the site's guidelines before posting.

Comment: Yeah, the tour of the code review site mentions 'best practice' questions of different forms in the _good questions_ and the _bad questions_ sections and it's not so clear cut. Still probably a better place than SO for such questions if asked properly.